# Force reauthenticate with adfs

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have seen a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938927/reauthenticate-using-adfs) but that was more related to ASP. I will explain my situation below.

I am developing a SP(Relying Party) and integrating with ADFS (IDP). Since I am in the integration phase, I want ADFS to forget that I have previously authenticated so that each time I hit the ADFS endpoint (/adfs/ls) with AuthnRequest, I want it to ask for my credentials.

I believe ADFS by default, remembers clients by their remote IP/host name so clearing cookies  on client machine does not help. There was a post that gave a link to logout from IDP (https:///adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https:///adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0). The ADFS says I have been logged out but when I hit ADFS endpoint, ADFS redirects back to SP with successful AuthResponse.

Can you please tell me how to force reauthenticate/logout on ADFS or point me to the right articles?

Comment: Also see my response in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938927/reauthenticate-using-adfs

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Answer (score 1):

The [FederatedPassiveSignInStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.controls.federatedpassivesigninstatus.aspx) control (which should be part of VS if you've installed all the WIF stuff) will help you. Add it to your app. and clicking it will log you out of everything.

Also [AD FS: How to Invoke a WS-Federation Sign-Out](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add `wfresh=0` as a URL parameter.

This parameter indicates "freshness requirements".

According to the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/os/ws-federation-1.2-spec-os.html#_Toc42337312):

> If specified, this indicates the desired maximum age of authentication specified in minutes.